# Bootstrap UI - $modal remains undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm reasonably new to Angular, and I'm having a weird problem when trying to use Angular Bootstrap UI.

I already know that it's being injected correctly, as the Typeahead component is working fine.  I'm just starting to switch old code that calls JQuery modals within the controller into bootstrap to make them more testable, but for some reason even though I inject $modal through to the controller, it remains undefined and I cannot use it.

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {};

(function (angular) {
    var common = MYAPP.common,
        controllers = common.controllers,
        directives = common.directives,
        factories = common.factories,
        filters = common.filters,
        services = common.services,
        repositories = common.repositories,
        application = angular.module('MyModule', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);



    application.directive('positiveInteger', directives.positiveInteger);

    application.filter('decimalPrecision', filters.decimalPrecisionFilter);

    application.service('httpService', ['$http', repositories.httpService]);

    MYAPP.application = application;

})(window.angular);
```

Then the module (loading in a seperate js file) :

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {},
    someModule = MYAPP.namespace('someModule');

(function (application) {


    /****************** Controller definitions **********************/
    application.controller('myController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modal', someModule.myController]);


})(MYAPP.application);
```

Then here's the controller code :

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {},
    someModule = MYAPP.namespace('someModule');


someModule.myController = function($rootScope, $scope, $modal) {
    var _controller = this;

etc etc
```

And then myController would be called with the above arguments, including the injected $modal.  $modal is undefined within the controller.

Weirdly I can see that ui.bootstrap is in there, as inspecting the loaded modules I can see it exists, as does the other components.  For example, angular.modules('ui.bootstrap') returns ok. If I mis-spell it, or enter a dummy name - it complains as I'd expect.

Interestingly the same applies if I enter a 'bad' injection annotation against the controller.  For example :

```
application.controller('myController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modalXXXYYY', someModule.myController]);
```

returns :

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalXXXYYYProvider <- $modalXXXYYY <- myController
```

I'm not sure what's going on here - or how to diagnose it.  I've checked obvious things like if it's being loaded in twice, but nothing like that seems to be going on.  It's quite a large application overall, so this is heavily simplified, but any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tony

Comment: did you forget to inject `$modal` into controller function? it's in dependencies array but function not shown

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I've updated with a snippet from the controller file above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured it out - and now I feel stupid.

Basically I wasn't persisting the passed in value in any way, so whilst $modal was passed across to the controller, the point where I was debugging (within a controller method) no longer had the variable in scope - which gave me the (false) impression that it wasn't actually passing it at all.

It was just a case of persisting the value to the controller e.g. _controller.modalService = $modal, and that sorted it out.